# Does KDB expose a more generic http handler function? (Any method, not just GET & POST)

Tags: kdb

I've been looking over the documentation and it doesn't look as though KDB provides an abstraction over a generic HTTP request only (GET & POST .z.ph/.z.pp look to be exposed).

I have a requirement to support other HTTP methods and was wondering if I have  overlooked the documentation or is it generally better to work around this limitation by using something through a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think KDB has a handler functions for other HTTP methods, atleast I am not aware of any. My other thought was if .z.ph/.z.pp functions are overloaded to support that but a quick testing confirmed that they do not support other http methods.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, its good to have someone with more context of k verify this.